# Deleting related records in diffrerent tables

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, while-loop

I have these three tables [ Orders, order_Items, order_comment ]

```
|    -Orders-    |     |  -Order_Items-   |     | -Order_comment- |
|    order_id    |     |  order_RegCode   |     |    order_id     |
| order_RegCode  |
```

As you can see, these three tables related together by 2 unique key! `order_id` and `order_RegCode`.

P.s: `order_RegCode` is not Primary Key and is a String!

i want when i delete any order by `order_id`, delete all related information that stored in two others tables. But when i using Do While i got `error Operation is not allowed when the object is closed`.

please guide me.

The Code is:

```
Dim Order_ID
    Order_ID = Int(Request.Form("ID"))

Set Conn = server.createobject("adodb.connection")
Conn.open StrConn
Set Rs = Conn.execute("SELECT * From orders WHERE order_id="& Order_ID &"")
If NOT Rs.EOF then

    RegCode = Rs("order_RegCode")

    '//== Delete Order
    Set Rs = Conn.execute("Delete From orders where order_id = "& orderID &"")

    '//== Delete All Comments Belong to Order
    Set Rs = Conn.execute("Select * From order_comment where order_id = "& Order_ID &"")
    If NOT Rs.EOF then
        Do While NOT Rs.EOF
            Set Rs = Conn.execute("Delete From order_comment where order_id = "& Order_ID &"")
        Rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End if

    '//== Delete All Items Belong to Order
    Set Rs = Conn.execute("Select * From order_items where order_code = '"& RegCode &"'")
    If NOT Rs.EOF then
        Do While NOT Rs.EOF
            Set Rs = Conn.execute("Delete From order_items where order_code = '"& RegCode &"'")
        Rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End if

End if
```

Comment: You'll have to show your code.  There's no way of knowing what the problem is without seeing your code, other than to say that the `operation is not allowed when the object is closed.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not use a recordset for action queries. These lines:

```
Set Rs = Conn.execute("Delete ...
```

Should be:

```
Conn.execute("Delete ...
```

You cannot use the same object for all recordsets. You will need a recordset for the outer loop and another for the inner loop. However, I suggest:

```
Dim Order_ID
Order_ID = Int(Request.Form("ID"))

Set Conn = server.CreateObject("adodb.connection")
Conn.Open StrConn
Set rs = Conn.Execute("SELECT * From orders WHERE order_id=" & Order_ID)
If Not rs.EOF Then

    RegCode = rs("order_RegCode")

    '//== Delete Order
    Conn.Execute ("Delete From orders where order_id = " & orderID)
    Conn.Execute ("Delete From order_comment where order_id = " & Order_ID)
    Conn.Execute ("Delete From order_items where order_code = '" & RegCode & "'")

End If
```

Comment: Can this code delete all comments related to this order? i cant see any loop?

Comment: Look at your code. You only set RegCode  in one place. You do not need a loop unless RegCode changes.

Comment: Thank You so much Remou. you guid me man. thank you for time spending